# Winrar extraction - Automatic choose?

Tags: extract, winrar

is there any way to automatic choose "Yes to all" button while extraction?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command line with: Switch -Y - assume Yes on all queries.

for further  info check [**winrar manual**](http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/):

Comment: Where can I add it?
winrar x -r "%D\*.zip" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\%N\"

Comment: winrar x -Y -r "%D*.zip" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\%N\"